# Lock file while writing in java

Tags: java, concurrency, io

On a server I have a xml file. The content can also be displayed and modified on the client side. To do that we have a view that can be used to change the content and save it. We have also some jobs that are scheduled to start at a certain time that will use the content of the file to make some computation. I would like to know the best practice in java to handle the lock of file while is being modified and the wait of jobs until the file is saved.

Comment: You can't. if somebody else would start another application which accesses the file, it wouldn't be able to see the lock. Unless you kept the information locally somewhere, in a properties, or a text file, and check that file for a status each time you tried to open the fle.

Comment: @Stultuske is right, if all the read/write lock happens in one jvm, then you can use ReentrantReadWriteLock [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/locks-concurrent/reentrantlock/java-reentrantreadwritelock-example/). Otherwise, you could use a new file on filesystem to judge whether your xml file can be updated or not.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we have a client server architecture, and the access to file is offered by a web service

Comment: @Stultuske is wrong. There are file locks in Java, but they only work if all affected JVMs try to use them. See `java.nio.FileLock` and friends.

Comment: @EJP that is one major 'if'

Comment: @Stultuske I mis-spoke. It will work as long as all affected *programs* use them, whether JVMs or otherwise, and it is an entirely accurate statement, unlike your 100% *inaccurate* statement. But if that's your answer, please post it as such so I can downvote it.

Comment: @EJP simply, you can't, because: 1. you can not guarantee that all affected programs use them. 2. even if they did, it is still possible to alter the file outside of any applications, without the Java applications to be aware of it.

Comment: @Stultuske You're changing the question. He wants to lock the file while it is being modified so that the jobs are made to wait. Not against arbitrary actions such as you describe.